# Better find object with ID in array of NSManagedObject

Tags: arrays, swift, nsmanagedobject

I am trying to find and update object in array of NSManagedObjects.

I have this code that I dislike:

```
    var dataInPhone = [NSManagedObject]()    // Here is data to update
    var index = 0
    for album in self.dataInPhone {
        if album.objectID == anObject.objectID {   // anObject 
            break
        }else{
            index += 1
        }
    }
    dataInPhone[index] = anObject as! NSManagedObject
```

Is any way to do it better?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a method `indexOf` which supports also a closure as argument

```
var dataInPhone = [NSManagedObject]()    // Here is data to update
...
if let index = dataInPhone.indexOf({$0.objectID == anObject.objectID}) {
  dataInPhone[index] = anObject as! NSManagedObject
}
```

Comment: I have declared anObject as `AnyObject` so i need to use `as! NSManagedObject`, but it's what i want. Thank you so much.

Comment: anObject is only declared in function header like `didChangeObject anObject: AnyObject`, but otherwise is an element of `fetchedResultsController.fetchedObjects` from Core Data

Comment: Swift recommends to cast `AnyObject` to the proper type as soon as possible for example `fetchedResultsController.fetchedObjects as! [NSManagedObject]`